# VPN раздача инета на растоянии WIn7

Tags: vpn

Доброго дня!Господа, необходимо раздать интернет по vpn между двумя компами находящиеся на большом расстоянии. В WinXP делалось все просто т.е. расшаривание интернета от провайдера и создание Входящего подключения и все... инет бежит. В Win7 так не получается...может кто сталкивался с этим?

Answer (score 1):

Может быть вот так: [VPN сервер Windows 7](http://forum.sysadmins.su/index.php?showtopic=40242747) ?

Comment: Спасибо, но  по ссылке расшаривание инета когда 2 юзера находятся в одной подести, а мне нужно когда юзеры в другой подсети